# jQuery mobile "pageinit" is not fired on first page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, page-init

I'm serving the html page via node.js server and `pageinit` event is not fired on initial page render. But when I start to navigate through pages on loaded app it works fine.

Any workaround?

Comment: Can you provide some code? Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @BarisAkar I've noticed that any of `pageXXXX` events are not fired when loaded pages are redirects..

Comment: @BarisAkar also please take a look on - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551932/jquery-mobile-routing-solution