# jQuery mobile routing solution?

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, dom, routes

I have a mobile app which was build with jquery mobile in a classic way - on every page transition html content is loaded via AJAX request and inserted into `data-role="content"` element.

What I want to refactor is client-side, there's an ugly code that finds specifc id in DOM in order to differentiate pages and run url dependant code.

```
...

if $page.find('#commentary').length
   unless @CommentaryView
       @CommentaryView = new CommentaryView
   @CommentaryView.render page
   return

if $page.find('#coupons').length
   unless @CouponsView
       @CouponsView = new CouponsView
   @CouponsView.render page
   return

...
```

Could you advice me some jquery-mobile routing solution? Or is it fine to keep find element by id routing? Thanks!

Comment: :bulb: if its really a legacy code, then avoid refactoring unless you have promises within code (tests), "big ball of mud / shantty town, YAGNI, if ain't  broken dont fix" and stuff, read this: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/advanced-routing-and-jquery-mobile `:)` also Clarify in more details with possible code sample as to ```there's an ugly code that finds specifc id in DOM in order to differentiate pages and run url dependant code.```? what exactly you mean by this.

Comment: @Tats_innit I've updated question with code example.